# Не подключается Ionic Framework и woocommerce api

Tags: angularjs, api, woocommerce, cordova, ionic

Создаю приложение под Ionic + WC-API.
При попытке получить доступ к товарам пишет не валидый ключ. Создал ключ в Woocommerce Админке. На просторах интернета нашел, что нужна еще аутентификация.
Вроде есть рабочей код, но вставляю код и не работает (state просто не открывается):
Раз: [Call WooCommerce 2.1 REST APT in Ionic Framework using Ouath1.a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889338/call-woocommerce-2-1-rest-apt-in-ionic-framework-using-ouath1-a)
Два: [santoshshinde2012.blogspot.ru/2016/03/woocommerce-rest-api-with-ionic.html#comment-form](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.ru/2016/03/woocommerce-rest-api-with-ionic.html#comment-form)

Ключи поставил свои.
Эти библиотеки скачал и подключил в index.html:

```
hmac-sha1.js
enc-base64.js
oauth-1.0a.js
oauth-signature.js
```

Но все равно не работает. Как получить список продуктов sitename.ru/wc-api/v3/products и пройти эту аутентификацию. Приложение дебажу в VisualStudio 2015 (локальный сервер с выходом в интернет - сеть есть). Когда делал вывод постов через WordPress API - все отлично работает, а с WC такая проблема.

Comment: Мало информации - где находится сервер WC, какие ошибки и ответы-запросы в консоле. Наиболее вероятно что у вас есть CORS ограничения и нет корректных хидеров, которые разрешают брауузеру внутри ionic делать запросы.